# How to get the User Agent of a user triggering a GTM event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, user-agent

I have a Data Layer event push in JS and was wondering if it is also possible to learn the User-Agent of the users triggering the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create variable which will return user agent

1) Go to Variables -> New

2) Name: `User Agent`

3) Type: `Custom JavaScript`

4) Code:

```
function () {return  navigator.userAgent;}
```

Then you can use this variable in your tags like that `{{User Agent}}`

Answer (score 5):

Even more simply, can't you use a "JavaScript Variable" (instead of a "Custom JavaScript" and then just set `navigator.userAgent`?

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics custom dimension field can be maximum 150 characters and user agent data (when encoded) usually exceed the limit. You need to find a way to shorten the user agent information within a custom js script before sending to GA. You may crop the first 150 character of the user agent information or remove the unnecessary sections or remove the blank characters.